# Postgres SERIAL column Autocommit gap

Tags: postgresql, autocommit

If I have table:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name(
    id SERIAL
);
```

And I have following id's inserted: ..., 68, 69.

Then I have 2 and I have to competing transactions (T1, T2) running in parallel. I understand that it could happened that transaction finishing first gets higher number because id is assigned and written in WAL before transaction commits.

`T1 (Take Number = 70), T2 (Take number = 71), T2 (Commit), T1(Commit)`

What is situation when having AUTOCOMMIT (When inserting row outside of transaction).
And I have to very close insert is id guaranteed that first inserted row will get lower number?

Use case is following:
After inserting row, I would execute `SELECT id FROM table_name ORDER BY id`. Could it happen that i execute this command twice once after another and then get following result:

Select 1 result: 68,69,71

Select 2 result: 68,69,70,71

Comment: You should not care about gaps in the numbers. They are normal, expected and nothing to worry about.

Comment: "When inserting row outside of transaction" - you can never work "outside of a transaction". If you use autocommit, every statement is a single transaction - but it's still a transaction.

Comment: I would advise reading the [Sequences](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createsequence.html) Notes section. It explains sequence behavior. Bottom line there will be gaps and ordering is not guaranteed.

Comment: It is not about gaps. I need to implement gapleas sequence. So my idea was to store event log with serial column. Then select all items that where added since last assigned sequence. And calculate my gapless  sequence. But since it coild hapen that after I insert new item and select, item from stalled transaction could appear in between, then this is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you don't use explicit transactions, it is not guaranteed that the statement that gets the lower sequence value will also commit first.